# OpenRefine: Extract substring of n sentences before & after a keyword using GREL

Tags: substring, openrefine, grel

I have a column with lengthy strings that I need to extract only a portion of to analyse. I need to extract a substring that contains the 5 sentences before and after occurrences of a keyword, excluding repeated sentences.

For example, the original cell structure might contain 4 mentions to the keyword:

> This is one sentence. And another. And another. And another. And another. And another. And another. And another. And another. Here, there is a first mention to the keyword. Another sentence. And
> another. And another. And another. And another. A second mention to
> the keyword. This is another. And another. And another. And another.
> And another. And another. And another. And another. And another. And
> another. A third mention to the keyword. And a forth mention. Another
> sentence. And another. And another. And another. And another. And
> another. And another. And another. And another. And another. And another. And another. And another. And another. And another. And another. And another. And another. And another. And another. And another. And another. And another. And another. And another. And another. And another. And another. And another. And another. (...) And another. And another.

The expected new cell would be:

> And another. And another. And another. And another. And another. Here, there is a first mention to the keyword. Another sentence. And
> another. And another. And another. And another. A second mention to
> the keyword. This is another. And another. And another. And another.
> And another. And another. And another. And another. And another. And
> another. A third mention to the keyword. And a forth mention. Another
> sentence. And another. And another. And another. And another.

Is there are a way to do this adding a column based on a column in OpenRefine with a GREL function? Thanks for your help!

Comment: For clarification:
1. How is a sentence defined in your data? Ending with a dot? Or do you have other punctuation marks in your data?
2. How should repeated sentences be handled? Are they included in the window size of 5 sentences before and after the sentence with the keyword? Should they get removed?
3. I assume a sentence is considered as repeating only in the search window around the sentence with the search keyword?
4. How to handle repeated sentences with the search keyword?
5. Do you have one or multiple search keywords?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the questions. 1. Sentences end with a dot. 2, 3 & 4. If a sentence is in the window of 5 sentences b&a keyword and is reputed, should be removed. 5. I have multiple, but I'll deal with them separately, otherwise could impact the repeated sentences rule.